Harmonic, partial, overtone. Which is which?
The three terms are bandied about, but there's often confusion as to what each one actually represents. What's what?

This question is similar to: What's the difference between overtones and harmonics?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I answered the question, but actually I think it's a duplicate.

@user1079505 - all three terms occur in an answer, but not in a question. Does that make t a dupe? As someone on the 'net asking the question may not be guided to an answer, maybe just a question. Not sure.

I answered a similar question ten years ago. It managed 4 dvs, with the usual no explanations. So, asking as I'm still not sure, and when someone on the net asks the question, this should turn up.


Overtones are any components of the sound above the fundamental frequency,
Partials are fundamental and overtones together,
Harmonics are partials whose frequencies are integer multiples of the fundamental.

See also Wikipedia article on Overtones.
